# How can I see number of columns and rows selected when I select a lot?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I think it used to be shown

Now all I see is something like this

[image]

It doesn't show

Usually it's shown on bottom left. Now in bottom left I see this logo if I hover

I see logo for quick analysis.

When number of rows and columns selected is small it shows on top left

[image]

But as numbers of columns go up, that number is gone.

Comment: Your question is unclear, but are you asking about the `name box` in excel? Once you let go of the mouse button, that will change to the first cell you clicked on when selecting that range. The behavior of that name box changes, depending if you scroll, or have locked any rows or columns, named ranges, etc. The tool-tip, however, should still show you how many rows and columns you have selected. Of course that goes away once you release your mouse button.

Comment: No. I do not see number of rows and columns anywhere. In the second screenshot there is 13R x 2C but those numbers are gone when number of rows are many. I do not see that info anywhere else

Comment: Seems to go away for me if I scroll beyond the visible screen and force Excel to auto-scroll. But the tooltip continues to show the numbers, as pointed out by @Isolated 
If you let go, the tooltip is gone, but you can just do a quick Shift+down arrow, up arrow to select an extra row then deselect it, and the tooltip reappears until you let go of shift.

Comment: @Adamv can you elaborate? Sometimes I see the tool tip but I am not sure. Sometimes it shows sometimes it doesn't. Usually in the lower right corner of the selection there is another place where rows and numbers are showing up but sometimes it's there sometimes it's not and another icon autofill or something is there